# Not able to use monkey talk of gorillalogic

Tags: android, iphone, ios, hybrid

I am  trying to use monkey talk which is a cross platform tool to test iPhone and android apps, but i am not able to use that.

When i am trying to use it with my iPhone simulator while selecting table view tab on monkey talk it is showing following error-
iOS Simulator connection error: connection to agent timed out

and when i select monketalk tab, it shows following-
WARNING: connectToiOSSimulator action invoked, but active window is not a FoneMonkeyConsole

Reference url - http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk

Comment: What are your impressions about this tool? Thumbs up or down?

Comment: @ReneBerlin- In terms of usability - thumbs up, but in terms of maturity - thumbs down.(We need to wait for a stable release that contains more functionality to fill the purpose.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling long, i am finally able to fix this issue.
I am setting wrong other linker flag due to which connection agent fails.
Other linker flag needs to be set to - -all_load -lstdc++

Answer (score 0):

workspace in use or can not be created monkeytalk error is seen while installing monkey talk